# How to strip html tags to email from $post?

Tags: php, jquery, html, strip

When I receive the result from a online quiz I've been doing,

I receive all the html tags in the email, (from the div #resultKeeper)
I'm looking to remove them, but how to ? If anybody can highlight me, it will be wonderful!

Here it is how I receive the email:

```
From: name
 Message: message
 Results:
 <div id=\"questionanswrs\"> Question 1 is true</div><div id=\"questionanswrs\"> Question 2 is false</div><div id=\"questionanswrs\"> Question 3 is true</div><div id=\"questionanswrs\"> Question 4 is false</div><div id=\"questionanswrs\"> Question 5 is false</div><div class=\"totalScore\"><br>Your total score is 2 / 5</div><div class=\"totalScoreok\"><br>CONGRATULATION, YOUR LEVEL IS A1.1</div>
```

Here is the jQuery part:

```
$(function() {
$('#quesForm').on('submit',function(e) { 
e.preventDefault();
// I am fetching the form values you could get them by other selectors too
var uname = $("input[name=username]").val(); 
var uemail = $("input[name=email]").val();
var msg = $("textarea").val()
$.post('submit.php',{username:uname,email:uemail,message:msg,results:$('#resultKeeper').html(),subject:'Subject of your e-mail'},function(result){
      // result variable contains your response text
      // I guess you trying to update your response 
     // notice I have used html(result) as you have just used html()
      $('#responseMessage').html(result);

});
  // you dont require `return false`
  // you have already did it using e.preventDefault();
});
 });
```

and my PHP:

```
<?php $name = $_POST['username'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $message = $_POST['message'];
   $results = $_POST['results'];
   $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message \n Results: \n $results";
   $recipient = "email@mail.com";
   $subject = "my subject";
   $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
   mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
   echo "Your email has been send, thank you";
  ?>
```

Thank you for everything!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strip_tags()` php function tries to return a string with all NULL bytes, HTML and PHP tags stripped from a given string.

**REF:** https://www.php.net/strip_tags

Answer (score 0):

try out this

```
$message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);
```

Comment: try to trace out the value of $message after stripping the tags.. check if there is still some tags

Comment: i got it by        $results = strip_tags($results); // add this to remove html tags and all
 cheers